# Error message "the specified module could not be found: (Exception from HResult: 0x8007007E)"

Tags: c#

Any time I try to transfer the model of my tables from the database (in sql Management studio) through linq to sql to my visual studio c#, I get the error message "the specified module could not be found: (Exception from HResult: 0x8007007E)". Can someone kindly assist on how I can resolve this.

Comment: One of your dependencies cannot be resolved.

Comment: Use dependencies walker. For more informations look here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6793785a-ec98-4453-a62b-f1a85195ec05/unable-to-load-dll-hresult-0x8007007e

Comment: Someone had a similar problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96eb73f3-f10f-4055-9348-dcea0d767e91/cannot-use-or-design-surface-linq-to-sql?forum=vseditor

Comment: Thanks so much, Evenhuis, I was able to resolve this problem from your link.